# MySQL error validators can't seem to find in syntax

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to build an SQL-Query with MySQL-Version 5.7.27.

I'm trying to make multiple left joins to the same table. At some point i get an error, that tells me, a column of the original table is unknown.

I tried finding the syntax error in my query, but there can't seem to be an obvious one. I tried out some online SQL-validators. They keep telling me, my query is valid.

After that i tried picking apart the query, to find out, what exactly i am working with before the left join that makes my query unable to function. Doing that actually showed me a result, that was including the column the error was telling me, that is missing.

So maybe it is not a syntax error, but MySQL is validating things in a order different to what i know, trying to pick the "missing" column out of somewhere it actually doesn't exist.

Changing the order of left joins actually solves the problem. I can't really do that, tho. The SQL is being generated by some functions. One for every part of the SQL. One for the "SELECT", one for the "FROM" and so on. So a working thing is joining the minimized versions of the "additional_agreement_fields" table before the other joins. Sadly the function for the "FROM" part is written ... in a very interesting way. So my best bet is adding the "additional_agreement_fields" joins after the function that creates the FROM.

That attempt generated the SQL below.

I get following error: 
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'customers.id' in 'on clause'

So: 
- The parts of the query are working on their own 
- Execution until the point of the error holds a table that has the 
  "missing column" 
- Changing the order of the joins solves the problem, but i can't just 
  do that and i want to know, why it doesn't work in this order 
- Online-validators can't find any syntax errors 
- Logically i am just adding columns to a table that are not ambiguous 
  and not removing any. Yet something becomes unable to be found

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (customers.id),
    companies.company_name AS 'Kunde -> Firmenname',
    vcpt_mail.tcom_value AS 'Kontakt -> TCom -> Email',
    v_contact_people.id AS 'Kontakt -> ID',
    v_contact_people.last_name AS 'Kontakt -> Nachname',
    A0.value AS 'Kunde -> Zusatzvereinbarung -> TestfeldB'
FROM
    customers
        LEFT JOIN
    customer_types ON customer_types.id = 
    customers.customer_type_id,
    v_customer_owners,
    companies
        LEFT JOIN
    (v_contact_people
    LEFT JOIN v_cp_tcoms AS vcpt_mail ON 
    vcpt_mail.contact_person_id = v_contact_people.id
    AND vcpt_mail.ttid = 3
    AND (vcpt_mail.type_label_access_path = '/Global'
    OR vcpt_mail.type_label_access_path LIKE '/Global%')) ON 
    v_contact_people.company_id = companies.id
    AND v_contact_people.access_path LIKE '/Global%'
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        additional_agreement_fields
    WHERE
        name = 'TestfeldB' AND value = '5') AS A0 ON customers.id 
        = A0.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        additional_agreement_fields
    WHERE
        name = 'TestfeldC' AND value = '6') AS A1 ON customers.id 
        = A1.customer_id
WHERE
v_customer_owners.customer_id = customers.id
AND v_customer_owners.path LIKE '/Global%'
AND customers.company_id = companies.id
AND companies.deleted_at IS NULL
AND customers.deleted_at IS NULL
AND (A0.value = '5' AND A0.name = 'TestfeldB'
OR A1.value = '6' AND A1.name = 'TestfeldC');
```

The expected result is a not empty table with 2 customers in it, i prepared to find and that are found, changing the join order.

The result is an interrupted query with an error code.

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'customers.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: ' If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html - fix your joins so that they are all explicit joins.

Comment: Thank you. Into the depths of the mysteriously written function, that creates the FROM part, i go.